# Parsing multiple objects in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a function below to `loadScript`, aka loading `css` and `js` files into `html` document `header` and `body` while detecting and avoiding duplicates. 
Initially, I use **_.type** as a switch condition but for that I have to define type: "js", when calling:

```
loadScript({
        type: "js",
        path: KERNEL +"/client/js/",
        ref: ["script1.js"]
    });

var loadScript = function(_){
    console.log(_.ref);
    var type = _.ref[0].slice(_.ref[0].lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    console.log(type);
    switch (type) {
        case 'js':
            _.ref.forEach(function(file){
                var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
                for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
                    var src = scripts[i].getAttribute('src');
                    if(src)
                    if(src.indexOf(file) > -1){
                        return;
                    }
                }
                var link = document.createElement('script');
                link.src = _.path + file;
                link.type = 'text/javascript'; link.async = true; // async = false if you need scripts loaded in sequence!
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(link);
            });
            break;
        case 'css':
            _.ref.forEach(function(file){
                for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++){
                    if(document.styleSheets[i].href.indexOf(file) > -1){
                        return;
                    }
                }
                var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                var link  = document.createElement('link');
                link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
                link.type = 'text/css';
                link.href = _.path + file;
                head.appendChild(link);
            });
            break;

        default:
            // code
    }
};
```

So I set it to **type** instead of **_.type**  in the switch to get rid of having to parse an additional parameter, BUT I can't do the following call:

```
loadScript({
            path: KERNEL+"/client/js/",
            ref: ["script1.js"]
        }, {
            path: PLUGIN_URL +"/js/",
            ref: ["process1.js", "process2.js", "ui.js"]
        },{
            path: UTILS_BOWER_URL+"/client/css/",
            ref: ["front2.css", "default.css"]
});
```

I don't want to have to do each (3x times):

```
loadScript({
            path: KERNEL+"/client/js/",
            ref: ["script1.js"]
        }); 

loadScript({
            path: PLUGIN_URL +"/js/",
            ref: ["process1.js", "process2.js", "ui.js"]
        });
```

References:

1. [async](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)
2. [environment](http://www.frontendjunkie.com/2012/04/dynamically-loading-javascript-files-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `arguments` for example:

```
function loadScript() {
  var length = arguments.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //do something
    console.log(arguments[i])}
}
```

[You can read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

Comment: OK, thanks. I backed down to my initial method of using loadScript() with slight chance below and it works:
`code`
        var _ = arguments[i];
        console.log(_);
        var type = _.ref[0].slice(_.ref[0].lastIndexOf('.')+1);
        console.log(type);
`code`

Comment: Also within the scope of my question, how to get `case 'js'` to work with either string or array of strings, so we can get rid of `[]` in defining, like:

`ref: "script1.js"`

but when passing `ref: ["process1.js", "process2.js", "ui.js"]`, everything still works fine. ???

Comment: hmm you can use the `typeof` method and convert the string into an array

Comment: `if (typeof ref === 'string') {
         ref = [ref];`
}

Comment: Actually, I tried without converting anything. 
The `.forEach` seems enough to interpret whether I'm passing a string or an array. So, it always works correctly regardless of what I'm passing there.

Tested on Chrome, haven't tried with other browsers. What's your opinion?

Comment: Problem with the loadScript() is that, I tried loading scripts in their right order `Jquery, Handlebars, jquery.typeahead.min.js, and my script` that requires Jquery and Jquery-Typeahead to work. In normal flow with all the `<script src...>`, everything works fine. With loadScript(), I added an array.push to log the info of what files have been loaded for me to verify. All were loaded but I encountered errors `jQuery is not defined`, `Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined (typeahead-plugin requires Jquery)` and `$.typeahead (my custom function) is not a function`. Why does that happen?

Comment: Interesting enough, I checked HTML source, all scripts were loaded in right order, same as the normal flow BUT errors above!. Is there any way to do loadScript() with promises? load Jquery .then( load Typeahead) . then( load my script) ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112193/discussion-between-pristine-kallio-and-akis-tfs).

Comment: better make a new question! so that the problem is clearly stated and also more people can have an opinion on this :D

Comment: My last edit and insertion of comment and reference show hints to fix it. I no longer have any issue with it.
The only flaw is that you need

`<script src="/path/to/file/thatcontainsloadScript.js" type="...></script>`

In order to start off everything. I have no workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by writing an extra method to do an upfront check to see whether the passing parameter is Array or Object.

```
var multipleScript = function(_){
    if (_ instanceof Array) {
        _.map(function(o){
            console.log(o);
            loadScript(o);
        })
    } else if ( _ instanceof Object)
        loadScript(_);
};
```

Now I can call, works fine, tested! But the downside of my solution is that, it has to be An Array [] inside! to apply same method to a set of objects.

```
multipleScript([{
            path: KERNEL+"/client/js/",
            ref: ["script1.js"]
        }, {
            path: PLUGIN_URL +"/js/",
            ref: ["process1.js", "process2.js", "ui.js"]
        },{
            path: UTILS_BOWER_URL+"/client/css/",
            ref: ["front2.css", "default.css"]
}]);
```